# Node.js how do you read a JSON with an element that is a HTTP address

Tags: json, node.js, auth0

OK I just ran into an issue.  I am using Auth0 to create users with different rights (not scopes just rights) in the App Metadata.  When I decode the Token I get this json:

```
{
  "iss": "https://testing.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|58e7bae154941844b507eaf5",
  "aud": "OSBkLd832tIhpDe0QFJbQ9vutgB2s6cJ",
  "exp": 1497016797,
  "iat": 1496980797,
  "https://thetestgroup.com/app_metadata": {
    "is_admin": true
  }
}
```

As you can see the app metadata is in the element "https://thetestgroup.com/app_metadata".  Normally I would just do something like this in my code (auth.payload.iat) to get the iat but for the app_metadata it rejects it because of the :.  Is there a good way to get at that data?

Comment: `auth.payload["https://thetestgroup.com/app_metadata"]`

Comment: That did not work.  I still just got back the whole payload not the app metadata

Comment: Sorry that did work.  For some reason my code was going down the wrong path so it was always passing everything.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok lets talk javascript (node) and your json

Firefox Scratchpad (Shift-F4)

```
var x = {
  "iss": "https://testing.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|58e7bae154941844b507eaf5",
  "aud": "OSBkLd832tIhpDe0QFJbQ9vutgB2s6cJ",
  "exp": 1497016797,
  "iat": 1496980797,
  "https://thetestgroup.com/app_metadata": {
    "is_admin": true
  }
}
x['https://thetestgroup.com/app_metadata'].is_admin // hit run
/*
true
*/
```

node.js

```
~ $ node -v
v8.1.0
~ $ node
> var x = {
...   "iss": "https://testing.auth0.com/",
...   "sub": "auth0|58e7bae154941844b507eaf5",
...   "aud": "OSBkLd832tIhpDe0QFJbQ9vutgB2s6cJ",
...   "exp": 1497016797,
...   "iat": 1496980797,
...   "https://thetestgroup.com/app_metadata": {
.....     "is_admin": true
.....   }
... }
undefined
> x['https://thetestgroup.com/app_metadata'].is_admin 
true
>
```

---

Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since pure JS and JSON are quite happily using the (strange) key - as demonstrated.

Comment: Yep you are correct.  I was able to get to the data I had a different mistake that was causing the issue for me not getting the right data.  Thanks for your help